# find solutions to following equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

This is an interview question. There are a total of 100 coins of values 5, 1, 0.2.
I need to find a solution that satisfies the following constraints.

1) The total number of coins must be 100.

2) The total value of coins must be 100.

3) There must be at least 1 coin of each type.

So basically i need to solve these equations. x+y+z = 100 and 5x+1y+0.2z=100.

I've written a java program to brute force the values and found that 16 solutions exist.

1)  1, 94, 5

2)  2, 88, 10

3)  3, 82, 15

4)  4, 76, 20

5)  5, 70, 25

6)  6, 64, 30

7)  7, 58, 35

8)  8, 52, 40

9)  9, 46, 45

10)  10, 40, 50

11)  11, 34, 55

12)  12, 28, 60

13)  13, 22, 65

14)  14, 16, 70

15)  15, 10, 75

16)  16, 4, 80

How do i go about solving this manually?

Comment: Please tell me how to improve the question before down voting.

Comment: Note:  I did not downvote the question, though I think what you have written is not clear.  In what sense is, e.g., $94,5$ a solution?

Comment: 1*5 + 94*1 + 5*0.2 = 100. those values satisfy both the equations. I just need to know how to get those answers by myself instead of writing a program to try all possible combinations.

Comment: Right, but as you can see you only wrote down a pair of numbers where a triple is required.  Are we meant to guess which coin corresponds to which number?  Why not just explain what you have written clearly?

Comment: i'm sorry that wasn't clear. the number are not indexed. the first value is actually part of the solution. i'll edit it to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the number of $5's$, $B$ the number of $1's$, and $C$ the number of $.2's$.  Clearly $C$ is divisible by $5$.  Also we have  $1≤C≤95$, which implies $5≤C≤95$.

Choose $C=5D$, for $1≤D≤19$.  For a given $D$ we then seek to solve the pair of equations $$A+B=100-5D \quad \&\quad 5A+B=100-D$$

Subtracting the former from the latter we see that $$4A=4D\implies A=D$$.

Thus your triples are of the form $(D,100-6D,5D)$.  Since we require $100-6D≥1$ we must have $99≥6D$ or $D≤16$ and we are done.

Comment: Can you explain how you concluded that 1≤C≤95?

Comment: Also how you concluded that C is divisible by 5 without knowing the value of C?

Comment: Sure.  Your question already requires $1≤C$. If $C$, which is divisible by $5$ remember, is greater than $95$ it must be at least $100$, but in that case we'd have $A,B≤0$.

Comment: $C$ is divisible by $5$ since $.2C=\frac C5=100-5A-B\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Start from $100$ coins of $1$.

If you turn $5$ of them to a coin of $5$, the number of coins decreases by $4$. You can compensate by turning a coin of $1$ to $5$ coins of $0.2$. In total, you consume $6$ coins of $1$.

After $k$ such operations, the configuration is $(k,100-6k,5k)$. There are $16$ solutions, from $(1,94,5)$ to $(16,4,80)$. (Note that $4=100\bmod6$.)